# ctrl+x in vim text editor doesn't work as expected

Tags: debian, path, autocomplete, vi, editors

I have Debian Jessie and vim terminal text editor. I try to autocomplete a file path in insert mode. When I type ctrl and x simultaneously no path completing is done but two chars are displayed:

> ^X

I had another Jessie installation two days ago and this worked properly but I had to reinstall Debian. Now path autocompletion doesn't work. How to fix it?

**edit:** My issue is shown on the gif. I press ctrl+x and no completion happens:

[image]

Comment: Do you mean vi or vim? I don't think vi has autocompletion.

Comment: Yes it's vim. You are right.

Comment: Does the problem still happen when starting `vim` with `vim -u NONE` ?

Comment: I installed vim and the problem disappeared. I will test this next time on fresh Debian installation.

Answer (score 2):

It is actually <kbd>^X^F</kbd>, as in screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: I know how it should work. But in my case pressing ctrl+x makes vim display literally ^X. Need help how to fix it.

Comment: @trzczy You're using `vi`, not `vim`. This feature is not available in `vi`.

Comment: @Kusalananda No, when I typed `vi` without filename the information appeared that this was VIM.

Answer (score -1):

I installed vim and it worked

```
apt-get install vim
```

**edit:** This is the solution.